# xamarin webview get console messages

Tags: xamarin, webview

I am using the WebView in a Xamarin Forms project.

In my application, is it possible to capture the Console messages generated by console.log ? Would the Javascript Bridge the only way to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the console during a debug session or during runtime with a released app?

Comment: during runtime of a released app - thanks

Comment: On Android you can subclass `WebView` (using `WebChromeClient`) and can create an override for `OnConsoleMessage`. On iOS, more work is needed, but there is a great OSS library, `WBWebViewConsole`, that handles UIWebView and MKWebView. You can create a binding project for it or use its source as a baseline for converting to C# (I created a binding project...)

Comment: thank you - very helpful